# Picture preview of video with TikZ (LaTeX) in PDF

Tags: tikz-pgf, animations, animate

I made an animation with TikZ/PGF for a PDF paper (not Beamer). The problem is that when the reader of the document is not Adobe (for example Mendeley -it is a free program for managing and sharing research papers- or CorelDraw - it is a vector graphics editor- programs), it sees a "white hole" instead of video (it does not even appear the preview figure of the video).

My question is: **What can I do to make for those PDF readers that do not support video animation? I want to the preview figure appears instead of video at least.**

When I open a PDF document with these animations directly from Gmail, the video does not appear but a preview figure appears instead of a video. But with other readers just "white hole" appears instead of it.

---

Example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,oneside,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{fp}                     % Calculos numéricos
\usepackage{textcomp,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{%
    decorations.pathreplacing, %
    decorations.pathmorphing, %
    snakes
}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{animate}

\newcommand{\tkApoyo}[4]{

    \tikzstyle{triangulo} =[line width=1pt, color=black, fill=gray]
    \tikzstyle{circulo} =[line width=1pt, color=black, fill=gray]
    \tikzstyle{base}=[snake=border, line width=1pt, raise snake=-6pt,segment length=5pt, segment amplitude=8pt, segment angle=45, color=black]

    \def\tkX{#2}
    \def\tkY{#3}
    \def\tkInc{0.6cm} 
    \def\tkRad{0.1cm}      

    \pgfmathparse{\tkInc*cos(60+#4)}    \let\tkIncX\pgfmathresult
    \pgfmathparse{\tkInc*sin(60+#4)}    \let\tkIncY\pgfmathresult

    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{fijo}}{

        \coordinate (D0) at (\tkX, \tkY);                                     
        \coordinate (D1) at ([xshift=\tkIncX, yshift=-\tkIncY] D0);           
        \coordinate (D2) at ([xshift=-\tkIncX, yshift=-\tkIncY] D0);          
        \coordinate (D3) at ([xshift=-1.65*\tkIncX, yshift=-\tkIncY] D0);     
        \coordinate (D4) at ([xshift=1.72*\tkIncX, yshift=-\tkIncY] D0);      
        \coordinate (D5) at ([xshift=-2.0*\tkIncX, yshift=-\tkIncY] D0);      
        \coordinate (D6) at ([xshift=1.9*\tkIncX, yshift=-\tkIncY] D0);       

        \draw[triangulo] (D0) -- (D1) -- (D2) -- cycle;
        \draw[circulo] (D0) circle (\tkRad);
        \draw[triangulo] (D3) -- (D4);
        \draw[base] (D5) -- (D6);
    }{

    }
}

\date{}

\newcounter{tiempo}
\setcounter{tiempo}{0}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{plain}

    \def\miPi{3.141592654}
    \def\f{1}
    \def\L{4.5}
    \def\A{2.2}

\tikzstyle{viga} =[line width=3pt, color=gray]
\tikzstyle{modo1} =[line width=1.5pt, color=red]

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
    \setcounter{tiempo}{0}
    \begin{animateinline}[autopause, loop, poster = first]{10}       % [loop, poster = first, controls]
      \whiledo{\thetiempo<58}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
            \clip (-0.6,-\A-0.1) rectangle (\L+0.5,\A+0.1);

            \begin{scope}[scale=1]
                \draw [viga] (0,0) -- (\L,0);
                \tkApoyo{fijo}{0}{0}{0}
                \tkApoyo{fijo}{\L}{0}{0}

                \draw[modo1] plot[smooth,domain=0:\L] (\x, {\A*cos(2*\miPi/\f*\thetiempo)*sin(\miPi*\x/\L r)});
            \end{scope}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \stepcounter{tiempo}
        \ifthenelse{\thetiempo<58}{
                \newframe
        }{
                \end{animateinline}\relax
        }
     }
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! But why did you link the examples of animations?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: are you using adobe reader for display? because the other readers can't handle the JS content.

Comment: Sorry to explain so bad my question, I've edited now improving it

Comment: All PDF viewers that I know of (including the firefox and chrome built-in viewers) are at least able to display the frame that was specified as the poster image (default: the first frame). I tested this with the animate [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/animate/animate.pdf). I recommend sending a bug report to the mendeley developers. CorelDraw is not a dedicated PDF viewer.